# fix this flutter CHATVIEW issue. i can't seem to get past it for days

Tags: flutter

Any time i send a message, the messages just keep going down and does not behave like a chatting interface.

- reverse = true, didnt work
- Listview , gives error
- Singlechildscrollview, gives error too

I cant continue coding further

[image: Screenshot here:]

```
 Class ChatPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String groupId;
  final String userName;
  final String groupName;

  ChatPage({this.groupId, this.userName, this.groupName});

  @override
  _ChatPageState createState() => _ChatPageState();
}

class _ChatPageState extends State<ChatPage> {
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _chats;
  TextEditingController messageEditingController = new TextEditingController();

  Widget _chatMessages() {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
      child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _chats,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          //reverse: true,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0, vertical: 90.0),
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return MessageTile(
                              message: snapshot
                                  .data.documents[index].data["message"],
                              sender:
                                  snapshot.data.documents[index].data["sender"],
                              sentByMe: widget.userName ==
                                  snapshot.data.documents[index].data["sender"],
                            );
                          }),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 10.0),
                        color: Colors.deepPurple,
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              child: TextField(
                                controller: messageEditingController,
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: "Send a message ...",
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white70,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                    ),
                                    border: InputBorder.none),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 12.0),
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                _sendMessage();
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                height: 50.0,
                                width: 50.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.pink,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                                child: Center(
                                    child:
                                        Icon(Icons.send, color: Colors.white)),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              : Container();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _sendMessage() {
    if (messageEditingController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      Map<String, dynamic> chatMessageMap = {
        "message": messageEditingController.text,
        "sender": widget.userName,
        'time': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      };

      DatabaseService().sendMessage(widget.groupId, chatMessageMap);

      setState(() {
        messageEditingController.text = "";
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    DatabaseService().getChats(widget.groupId).then((val) {
      // print(val);
      setState(() {
        _chats = val;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                //bluegradient below
                Color(0xFF3366FF),
                Color(0xFFCC00CC),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        title: Text(widget.groupName,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 27.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
            )),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          _chatMessages(),

          // Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this issue because at the moment you send your message and want to scroll to the bottom your ListView has not been rebuild yet and it does not contains your latest message. The only solution I have found for now is to scroll above the expected limit of your list as you know you will have another element to display.

Here is how I have modified your code:

```dart
_sendMessage() {
    if (messageEditingController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      Map<String, dynamic> chatMessageMap = {
        "message": messageEditingController.text,
        "sender": widget.userName,
        'time': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
      };

      DatabaseService().sendMessage(widget.groupId, chatMessageMap);

      // Scroll to bottom of list programmatically
      _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent +
          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height);

      setState(() => messageEditingController.text = "");
    }
  }
```

I have added a `ScrollController` to your `ListView` and scrolling to its current limit (with `_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent`) and adding the height of your phone screen to ensure that you will see the last message. The scrolling automatically correct itself right after so you will be able to see your newly send message.

[You can see and test my entire code on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/1dfc5cd3dd04f62c567b00b8baec3b3b?)

Comment: You are great!!!!, i really do appreciate...for your timely respose and helping me fix this up...IT WORKED.

Comment: I'll still appreciate anyone with any fixes and help but right now the code above is PERFECT and im cool...